# React To Do List, How to add another item to a localStorage key array

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I've managed to work out how to give the note key in localStorage a value from the addNote page but I can't seem to work out how to make it so that it creates a new value under the note key and not just re-assigning the note value. I'm believe having either a for loop which will loop to the next array index or if statement would fix this issue and allow for the adding of items however I'm just unsure where to place it. Any help in working this issue out would be greatly appreciated :)

Download React project files here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_P85WUmyY9QcZu14-Ib8IxAU3e4UtZCp

Below is the code I'm using to get a input value and add it to the note key in a file called storage.js (located in src/services/storage.js)

```
class AddNote extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            //title: [],
            //content: []
            items: []

        }

        let note = getLocalItem(keys.note);

        if(!note) {
        note = [];
        }

        this.addNote = this.addNote.bind(this);
    }

    addNote(event) {
        console.log("Working")

        if( this.theTitle.value !== "" ) {
            var newItem = {
                title: this.theTitle.value, 
                content: this.theContent.value
            };
        }



        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                items: prevState.items.concat(newItem)
            };
        });



        const form = {
            title: this.state.title,
            content: this.state.content
        }




        setLocalItem('note', this.theTitle.value + " - " + this.theContent.value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just wan't to add the next content field 'note' to the existing value in the localStorage... the following code reads the localStorage value on componentDidMount; and then on each click of the button, updates (instead of replace) the localStorage array...

relevant **component**:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputs: [],
      lastInput: ''
    };
    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getExistingArray();
  }

  getExistingArray() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('inputs')) {
      var storedInputs = localStorage.getItem('inputs');
      this.setState({ inputs: storedInputs }, function () { console.log("from localStorage We got:", this.state.inputs); });
    }
  }

  click() {
    var newInput = [...this.state.inputs, this.state.lastInput];
    localStorage.setItem('inputs', newInput);
    this.getExistingArray();
  }

  recordInput(e) {
    this.setState({ lastInput: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='text' onChange={this.recordInput.bind(this)} />
        <button onClick={this.click}>Click to update the Array</button>
        <br /> Array: {this.state.inputs}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

complete [working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-x11cy7)

**UPDATE**: following function updated in light of questioner's comment

```
  click() {
    var newInput = [...this.state.inputs, this.state.lastInput];
    localStorage.setItem('inputs', newInput);
    this.getExistingArray();

    var newInputTag = 'inputs' + this.state.inputs.length;
    localStorage.setItem(newInputTag, this.state.lastInput);
  }
```

**UPDATE2**:
All local storage objects retrieved and printed on the page

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputs: [],
      lastInput: '',
      localStoragePairs: []
    };
    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getExistingArray();
  }

  getExistingArray() {

    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {

      var key = localStorage.key(i);
      var value = localStorage.getItem(key);

      var updatedLocalStoragePairs = this.state.localStoragePairs;
      updatedLocalStoragePairs.push({ 'keyName': key, 'valueName': value });

      this.setState({ localStoragePairs: updatedLocalStoragePairs });
    }
    console.log("complete localStoragePairs:", this.state.localStoragePairs);

    if (localStorage.getItem('inputs')) {
      var storedInputs = localStorage.getItem('inputs');
      this.setState({ inputs: storedInputs }, function () { console.log("from localStorage We got:", this.state.inputs); });
    }
  }

  click() {
    var newInput = [...this.state.inputs, this.state.lastInput];
    localStorage.setItem('inputs', newInput);
    this.getExistingArray();

    var newInputTag = 'inputs' + this.state.inputs.length;
    localStorage.setItem(newInputTag, this.state.lastInput);
  }

  recordInput(e) {
    this.setState({ lastInput: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    var LocalSotrageContent = this.state.localStoragePairs.map((value, index) => {
      return <tr key={index}> <td>{value.keyName}</td>  <td>{value.valueName}</td> </tr>
    });


    return (
      <div>
        <input type='text' onChange={this.recordInput.bind(this)} />
        <button onClick={this.click}>Click to update the Array</button>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>All Local Storage objects by Name</th>
              <th>All Local Storage objects by Value</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {LocalSotrageContent}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When testing the code it is updating the existing array and not creating a new value just like there would be when creating multiple to do notes/comments. By chance do you know a way to add a new note. Thanks

Comment: creating multiple values is not an issue... would you need to read those too?

Comment: Yes please I will first need to be able to add multiple values to my note key and then I can use the update code you sent me above.

Comment: Sorry but I'm pretty new to react and I'm unsure of what's entirely going on but it still seems that the same array is only being affected and there is no new array being made to hold a new note.

Comment: Go to developer tools > application tab > local storage to see the new items created on each click of th button

Comment: Oh I see thank you I will try and implement it to my project now

Comment: I would appreciate if you accept this answer so that others can benefit in the future also

Comment: One more thing do you know to display each item from the array in a list format on the page? So that it will display each input below each other. Thanks

Comment: @KarMadz, you unaccepted the answer :( ... however, your scenario is updated in the answer and stackblitz